# QTMovieView supported formats

Tags: macos, cocoa, quicktime

I am developing a media player using QTKit framework in Mac OS X (v 10.6). I have used QTMovieView control for the same but there is a problem. The issue is that mov files are played perfectly but avi files and similar formats are not playing properly by properly I mean that though I have added a document type for public.avi file type but only sound is coming and there is no visual output in the player. Been trying to play the same using Quicktime (v 10) but no avail.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

AVI as well as MOV are just movie containers. Usually a movie file contains a video track and an audio track. When in comes to playback it depends on the particular codecs used to compress the tracks. Quicktime can read AVI files, but it needs the certain codec to play the video.

You need to find out what video codec was used in your movie. There are number of apps that can display this information. For example VLC Player.

If Quicktime does not play it with default set of codecs, most likely the codec is Divx.

After you have found out what codec is used install the certain Quicktime component.

Comment: sorry for the late response, been havin some problems with the net lately..Thanks for the answer will get back at you once I am done implementing what you suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationProgrammingGuide/AnatomyoftheQTKFramework/AnatomyoftheQTKFramework.html)..and see [supported formats.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationProgrammingGuide/AnatomyoftheQTKFramework/AnatomyoftheQTKFramework.html).

**Audio formats**

> AIFF, MP3, AU, WAV, uLaw

**Video formats**

> AVI, AVR, DV, M-JPEG, MPEG-1, MPEG-2, MPEG-4

**Codecs**

> AAC, AVI, AVR, DV, M-JPEG, MPEG-1, MPEG-2, MPEG-4, , OpenDML, 3GPP,
>   3GPP2, AMC, H.264

**Web streaming formats**

> HTTP, RTP, RTSP

Comment: this is true .. but the file doesn't play in QTMovieView. Doesn't give any error but there is no visual content..!

Comment: yes i have but none of them is displayed visually in the player only sound is there...Sure thing the file is opened but not played properly.. No fancy code used apart from a new document type created for public.avi files..

Comment: could there be any issue with the qtmovieview ..? Because I guess that qtmovie is opening the file correctly..!

Comment: at last I found the problem !  The avi file was compressed , after I uncompressed the avi file (using ffmpeg) it played perfectly in the qtmovieview player...Now the problem is that every time it becomes a bit difficult to convert the file and then play it .. Is there some kind of provision that allows us to play files without decompressing them in qtmoviewview player..?